# BASH: Strip new-line character from string (read line)

Tags: windows, linux, bash, samba

I bumped into the following problem: I'm writing a Linux bash script which does the following:

- Read line from file
- Strip the `\n` character from the end of the line just read
- Execute the command that's in there

Example:
commands.txt

```
ls
ls -l
ls -ltra
ps as
```

The execution of the bash file should get the first line, and execute it, but while the `\n` present, the shell just outputs "command not found: ls"
That part of the script looks like this

```
 read line

        if [ -n "$line" ]; then #if not empty line

                #myline=`echo -n $line | tr -d '\n'`
                #myline=`echo -e $line | sed ':start /^.*$/N;s/\n//g; t start'`

                myline=`echo -n $line | tr -d "\n"`
                $myline  #execute it

                cat $fname | tail -n+2 > $fname.txt
                mv $fname.txt $fname
        fi
```

Commented you have the things I tried before asking SO. Any solutions? I'm smashing my brains for the last couple of hours over this...

Comment: have you simply tried `$line` alone?

Comment: Of course I did. But it says "command not found: ls
"

Comment: All that is needed is: `myline="$(echo -n "$line")"` (with backquotes instead of `$()` if you want)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I always like `perl -ne 'chomp and print'` , for trimming newlines. Nice and easy to remember.

e.g. `ls -l | perl -ne 'chomp and print'`

**However**

I don't think that is your problem here though. Although I'm not sure I understand how you're passing the commands in the file through to the 'read' in your shell script.

With a test script of my own like this (test.sh)

```
read line
if [ -n "$line" ]; then
  $line
fi
```

and a sample input file like this (test.cmds)

```
ls 
ls -l
ls -ltra
```

If I run it like this `./test.sh < test.cmds`, I see the expected result, which is to run the first command 'ls' on the current working directory.

Perhaps your input file has additional non-printable characters in it ?

mine looks like this

```
od -c test.cmds 
0000000    l   s      \n   l   s       -   l  \n   l   s       -   l   t
0000020    r   a  \n                                                    
0000023
```

From your comments below, I suspect you may have carriage returns ( "\r" ) in your input file, which is not the same thing as a newline. Is the input file originally in DOS format ? If so, then you need to convert the 2 byte DOS line ending "\r\n" to the single byte UNIX one, "\n" to achieve the expected results.

You should be able to do this by swapping the "\n" for "\r" in any of your commented out lines.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the file is written from Windows in a samba share and I totally forgot that I should look for a `\r` instead of `\n`. Up one vote from me and many thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this insight. I was generating output from sqlite3 using csv mode on __linux__, but the output seems to have had \r\n terminators. I wasted a lot of time before seeing your comment and realising that was the problem ...

Answer (score 14):

Someone already wrote a program which executes shell commands: sh file

If you really only want to execute the first line of a file: `head -n 1 file |sh`

If your problem is carriage-returns: `tr -d '\r' <file |sh`

Comment: Yes, of course, but that part of my batch file. It's more than a simple execute command from file, cause if it was just this I've used for sure only `sh`

Answer (score 3):

You may also try to replace carriage returns with newlines only using Bash builtins:

```
line=$'a line\r' 
line="${line//$'\r'/$'\n'}" 
#line="${line/%$'\r'/$'\n'}"       # replace only at line end
printf "%s" "$line" | ruby -0777 -n -e 'p $_.to_s'
```

Comment: I used similar approach to remove the trailing CR and/or LF: `x=${x//[$'\r\n']/}`. I love this solution as it does not call external utils, mostly not `perl`, which is very expensive to launch.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this:

```
read line
echo -n $line | od -x
```

For the input 'xxxx', I get:

```
0000000 7878 7878
```

As you can see, there is no `\n` at the end of the contents of the variable. I suggest to run the script with the option `-x` (`bash -x script`). This will print all commands as they are executed.

[EDIT] Your problem is that you edited commands.txt on Windows. Now, the file contains CRLF (0d0a) as line delimiters which confuses `read` (and `ls\r` is not a known command). Use `dos2unix` or similar to turn it into a Unix file.

Comment: The thing is i don't read from keyboard. I change my STDIN to a file (the command.txt from above) and if I echo the $line in between '' I get the output 'ls
'

Comment: The ouput I get on `echo -n $line | od -x` is "0000000 736c 000d
0000003"

Comment: The 0d is a carriage return. Not the same thing as a newline

Comment: AH! You edited that file on Windows and now, you have CRs in it! Use dos2unix or a similar script to convert CRLF (0d0a) to LF (0a).

Comment: +1, I know better, but for some reason I used Windows. This helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need eval command

```
#!/bin/bash -x

while read  cmd
do
 if [ "$cmd" ]
 then
  eval "$cmd"
 fi
done
```

I ran it as
./script.sh < file.txt

And file.txt was:

```
ls
ls -l
ls -ltra
ps as
```

Answer (score 0):

though not working for `ls`, I recommend having a look at [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)’s `-print0` option

Answer (score 0):

The following script works (at least for me):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read I ; do if [ "$I" ] ; then $I ; fi ; done ;
```