# Unix script - stripping CR and LF to pass to variable

Tags: bash, unix

I’m reading a text file, which looks like this:-

```
5.201270    5.201270    01

695.222611  695.222611  02

1258.098134 1258.098134 03

1565.198897 1565.198897 04
```

And parsing the input to send to ffmpeg

```
while read -r thisFinish finish nom
do
    outFile="${nom}.mp3"
    ffmpeg -i  "$inpFile" "$outFile"
done <"$labelFile"
```

I'm guessing that because `$nom` is reading from the end of line in the file, there’s a `CR` or `LF` there, so it's not sending `.mp3` to `ffmpeg`. How do I strip the end of line data from `$nom`? So it sends the command line `ffmpeg -i  "$inpFile" 01.mp3`

Comment: possible duplicate of [BASH: Strip new-line character from string (read line)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459250/bash-strip-new-line-character-from-string-read-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested this on `linux`

First set `carriage return` into a variable

```
 x=$'\r'
```

Then use [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to delete it from `${nom}`

```
 while read -r thisFinish finish nom; 
 do
     outfile="${nom%$x}.mp3"
     ffmpeg -i  "$inpFile" "$outFile"
 done < "$labelFile"
```